# Timing of route execution/database changes in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I currently have an ec2 instance and an rds instance running in AWS. I wish to know of the times that certain functions/routes/db changes were initiated/activated over the past couple of days. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "functions/routes/db changes"? Are you referring to maintenance updates of the Amazon RDS database? What do you mean by "functions" and "routes"?

Comment: so every time a get/post route gets executed by a user using the application on the internet, I want to be able to know when this occurs. And by database changes, I want to know when a user does a particular action that changes a value in the database.

Comment: You could add logging to your application. Depending upon what you mean by "I want to know", you could simply look in the log file. If you mean "I want to be immediately notified", then you could use Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) to send you an email or an SMS.